# Missing "Code Coverage" tab on Python project

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, pytest, vstest

I have a Python project hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/cmd-call-graph), which I test using [Azure Pipelines](https://dev.azure.com/cmd-call-graph/cmd-call-graph) (here is a [link to the configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/cmd-call-graph/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml)).

I am running unit tests with `pytest` and get coverage results, which I upload in my pipeline. I get an overall code coverage percentage in the pipeline execution summary ([example](https://dev.azure.com/cmd-call-graph/cmd-call-graph/_build/results?buildId=9&view=results)), but I don't see a "Code Coverage" tab that contains the details of which lines are covered. The build artifacts contain the HTML code coverage report, which contains this information, but it'd be nicer to see it in the pipeline run page itself.

Here is the invocation of pytest:

```
pytest tests --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml 
    --cov=callgraph --cov-report=xml --cov-report=html
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that doesnt work like that, unfortunately. at least that was the case 6 months ago.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7703

Comment: From this page, I was assuming it should be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-code-coverage-results?view=vsts

Comment: i'm not following ADO release cycle, so cant tell you, but if you are uploading coverage results (and it looks like you are) its probably not available yet, but dont quote me on this

Comment: That page shows the HTML coverage report which you can download from the artefacts tab. There is no in-ui experience for showing coverage and the HTML/CSS/JS produced by the test tools isn't inlined due to security reasons.

Comment: so pretty much what I've said? @jessehouwing